# Text after the last slash, what is my mistake?

Tags: php, url, replace

I want to get out of the URL after the last slash "/" the text. The page URL is very variable, for example:

http://mydomain.com/colors/productname.html
(result is "productname") OK!

http://mydomain.com/colors/size/zip/shipment/
(result is "shipment") OK!

or

http://mydomain.com/colors/
(result is "null") Null!

It works well so far except for the last example. Once, just a slash "/" after the domain name is I get no result.

What is my mistake?

Thanks in advance!

```
$url = "variable"       
if (strpos($url,'.h') !== false) {
$url = preg_replace('/\.h.*/', '/', $url);}
$url = rtrim($url, "/");
$str = substr(strrchr($url, '/'), 1);
$str = str_replace('-',' ',$str);
$keys = str_replace('/ /', '%20', $str);
$metric = urlencode($keys);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php already has a function that does this its called [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
$url = "http://mydomain.com/colors/";
echo basename($url);

//outputs 
colors

$url = "http://mydomain.com/colors/productname.html";
echo basename($url);

//outputs 
productname.html
```

Answer (score 2):

What is stopping you from using [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)?

```
<?php
  $url  = "http://mydomain.com/colors/";
  $url  = basename( $url ); //outputs "colors"
  echo $url;
?>
```

Or if you dont want the "`.html`" in output, you can use [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) with `PATHINFO_FILENAME` flag

```
<?php
  $url  = "http://mydomain.com/colors.html";
  $url  = pathinfo( $url, PATHINFO_FILENAME ); //also outputs "colors"
  echo $url;
?>
```